# How to make scrollview scroll when image is moved towards edge of the scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, scrollview

This could be pretty difficult to explain, but here we go, I'll try.

I would like to do what other apps do when the user drags an image for example to the bottom of the screen and the page scrolls, or like on safari when the user is highlighting text and they drag one end of the selector to the bottom and the scrollview scrolls. I'd also like the scrolling to speed up as the image the user is dragging gets closer to the edge of the screen.

So far I've only found questions similar to this for android but not for iPhone but feel free to direct me to one that I missed.

Thanks

Comment: try setting the content offset of uiscrollview.

Comment: But wouldn't that just move straight to a position? It wouldn't scroll at a constant speed would it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. Check this out http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1998968&seqNum=13

Comment: I don't think so, although I don't fully understand what it is that the article is about.